# How can I handle a click even when a user click on a BitMapField?

Tags: blackberry, click, bitmapfield

Here is my class, very simple:

```
public class SelectYesNoArea extends Manager {

    BitmapField yes;
    BitmapField no;
    DateField date;
    Calendar cal;

    public SelectYesNoArea(long style){
        super(style);           

        Bitmap bgPic = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("divBackgrounds.png");
        Background bg = BackgroundFactory.createBitmapBackground(bgPic);
        setBackground(bg);

        cal = Calendar.getInstance();               
        date = new DateField("",cal.getTime().getTime(), DateFormat.DATE_SHORT);
        add(date);

        Bitmap bitYes = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("yes.png");
        yes = new BitmapField(bitYes);
        add(yes);

        Bitmap bitNo = Bitmap.getBitmapResource("no.png");
        no = new BitmapField(bitNo);
        add(no);
    }   
}
```

I just want to handle when a user taps on the bitmapField. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an anonymous class:

```
yes = new BitmapField(bitYes) {
    trackwheelClick(int status, int time) {
        Do whatever you want here !
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `Field.FOCUSABLE` style when creating your BitmapField.